# Can I make a struct start with n-th field in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Whenever I create a structure, it starts from field 1 by default. I am working with a data file where I have to loop through a part of it to get data to create  the structure. In this small example, I loop only through 3 to 5, skipping 1 and 2.

```
for i = 3:5
    a(i).b = 1;
end
```

The result is a structure with empty 1 and 2 fields:

```
   b
1  []
2  []
3  1
4  1
5  1
```

Is there a way to start a struct with n-th field so it looks like this:

```
   b
3  1
4  1
5  1
```

The reason I want to do this is because in my real structure I get about 100 empty fields before 10 fields with the data and it doesn't look very neat.

Comment: I don't think so, as MATLAB's indexing uses the natural numbers (i.e. all integers of 1 and larger). Starting a struct at field 3 therefore would violate that indexing procedure. Can't you simply shift your data a couple of fields back, to fill in the empty cells and shift back whenever you require the data?

Comment: The result is _not_ a structure with 2 empty fields. The result is an array containing 2 structs with an empty field `b` and 3 structs with the field `b` set to 1.

Comment: @dasdingonesin no, you are incorrect. `a` is a `1 x 5` struct, with 1 field, `b`, of which the first two entries are empty, and the following three are `1`. Try it for yourself. This is *not*  an array

Comment: @Adriaan: Just run the first code block in MATLAB, then type `a` and tell me what you get.

Comment: Maybe a different datatype will solve your problem? e.g. [`table`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-table.html)

Comment: @dasdingonesin Struct array is an array of structures, I think

Comment: @ArthurTarasov indeed it is: consider `a(1).b=2; a(2).b=3; [a a]` returns a `1 x 4` struct array.

Comment: @ArthurTarasov: That's what I tried to say.

Comment: Then it's not what *I* tried to say:D I believe "struct array" and "array of structs" is the exact same thing in MATLAB.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: Absolutely. However, those things are not the same as a structure _containing_ an array in some field. I read "structure with empty 1 and 2 fields" in the original question and suspected that the author had trouble understanding how MATLAB structs work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the explicit question, there is no way to do this with a MATLAB [`structure`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html). You could use a [map container](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html) to store your data.

For example:

```
keys =  [3, 4, 5, 6];
values = [1, 1, 1, 1];
a = containers.Map(keys, values);
```

And you can access your data using `a(3)`, `a(6)`, etc.

That said, the memory overhead for empty structures is minimal, the difference between initializing your array with `for ii = 3:5` and `for ii = 1:3` is 16 bytes.